# XML Pretty Printer Missing 2 Key Edge Cases

Tags: xml, ruby, xslt, nokogiri, pretty-print

Using [this xslt file](http://www.printk.net/~bds/indent.html) found on [this blog](http://emmanueloga.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/pretty-printing-xhtml-with-nokogiri-and-xslt/) to pretty print xml using Nokogiri, everything *almost* works, but to the point where I can't use it for HTML.

First, if a node is empty, it turns it into a self closing node, so:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

gets converted to

```
<textarea/>
```

But that messes up the html tree when rendered.

Second, if the node just has text, the text isn't tabbed, and the closing node isn't tabbed, so:

```
<li>
 <label>some text</label>
</li>
```

becomes:

```
<li>
 <label>some text
</label>
</li>
```

...but it would ideally be:

```
<li>
 <label>
  some text
 </label>
</li>
```

Does anyone who's pro at XSLT know a quick fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the `xsl:output` element to indicate you want HTML output and indenting:

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only trying to pretty-print output and not concerned with any further transformations offered by XSL then just use http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify

You can also use a parameter for HTML http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify&html that treats certain tags as singletons even though they look like opening tags, such as <br> instead of <br/>.